# How can i use two extended classes in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am learning about java inheritance and i am a bit confused, if i write a program that handles 3 files:

```
    1) cheese.txt
    2) fruits.txt
    3) drinks.txt
```

If i have a parent class called Food that handles fruits.txt

and a class Cheese that handles cheese.txt that extends Foods
and a class Drinks that handles drinks.txt that extends Foods

so it looks like this

```
    class Foods {
    
          // code 
    }
    
    class Cheese extends Foods {
    
          // code
    }
    
    class Drinks extends Foods {
    
          // code
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
           Foods one = new Foods("fruits.txt");   // call to constructors 
           Cheese two = new Cheese("cheeses.txt");   // call to constructors
           Drinks three = new Drinks("drinks.txt"); // call to constructors
    }
```

How ever upon running this code it seems like the last class (Drinks) overlaps all the other classes. If i comment out the object three it works properly. How can i use all 3 classes in the main method at one time?

Comment: I'm stuck at the idea that a Cheese **is** a Fruit.

Comment: But what do you mean by "overlaps" other classes? The code creates 3 variables of 3 different classes.  All this is reasonable-ish (the variables could be better named).  If you've got trouble, it must be in the code you have not shown.  What is "working properly" versus not working? There's no code visible that does anything.

Comment: by "overlaps" i mean that when i print each file for example if i did cheese.print() (which prints the cheese.txt file) it will print the drinks.txt defined in the Drinks class below it. Or even if i try to do fruits.print (prints fruit.txt file) it will output the drinks file. It seems like the Drinks class which is defined last overrides all the other classes above it

Comment: Then your implementation is buggy.  Either you cut'n'pasted something wrongly, or (maybe more likely) you're misusing static member variables.  But in order to debug code, **we have to see the code**.

Comment: Also one more important thing to note is that if i comment out ```Drinks three = new Drinks("drinks.txt");``` it works fine when printing the fruits.txt and cheese.txt. Its like the extra extended class ```three``` messes it up```

Comment: Believe it or not my code does have static in it quite a lot isnt static used to define global variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242862/discussion-between-programme3219873-and-passer-by).

Comment: `static` is used to define *class* variables, which are a bit like global variables, although Java has no true global variables. You should almost certainly not be using `static` at all in a program like this. The values for each class should be held in *instance* variables which are not `static`.

Comment: i have found the bug it turns out static was the problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like others suggested you to do, you should show us the class with all the code in it so it would be easier for us to help you.

Second of all, you need to check all those things :
(good source of "documentation" is https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp) 
1- Check if you have all your imports right :

> import java.io.File;  // Import the File class 
> import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files

2- Check if you code is something similar to that :

> File myObj = new File("filename.txt"); // allows you to "bind" the file and use it for manipulations
> Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj); // allows you to do manipulations on your determined file 
> while (myReader.hasNextLine()) { // make sure that as long as there is another line that the reader has not read, it continues to read the file 
> String data = myReader.nextLine(); // where the read line is stored 
> System.out.println(data); // print the determined line

If you could show us both the super-class and the inheriting classes, it would